# Triangles and straight line (hint)

Tags: geometry

Let $D$ be the midpoint of the hypotenuse $BC$ of the right angled $\Delta ABC$. How can we prove that $2AD = BC$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Find a point $E$ so that $ABEC$ is a rectangle, and draw the two diagonals of that rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you find a point $E$ on $AB$ such that $\angle BED = \angle DEA = 90°$ and $E$ is the midpoint of $BA$. This can be done with the help of the Midpoint Theorem in triangles.

After doing that, you may proceed to show that $\triangle BED \equiv \triangle DEA$. Now, you may apply C.P.C.T to get the required result.